# How do I create a GUI app in C# with Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c#, user-interface, visual-studio-code

I want to create a GUI app in C# so I went to Youtube and watched some tutorials but all of them where using Visual Studio, not Visual Studio Code.

How can I write a GUI app in VS Code and not Visual Studio?

Comment: As VS code does not contain any UI designers - just code editors - you will have a hard time programming a GUI. But certainly it is possible e.g. using HTML. Why not use Visual Studio?

Answer (score 12):

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

namespace program{
    class program{
        private static void Main(){
            Form mainForm = new Form();
            Label lblFirst = new Label();
            mainForm.Width = 300;
            mainForm.Height = 400; 
            lblFirst.Text = "Hello World";
            lblFirst.Location = new Point(150,200);
            mainForm.Controls.Add(lblFirst);
            Application.Run(mainForm);
        }   
    }
}
```

There is simple hello world app which was done without Visual Studio. Every control is class in C#. You should create new object from these classes and you'll prepare all properties manual just like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, vscode is basically a rich text editor with extension, visual studio is a full IDE, it has built in templates, full solution analysis, and most importantly it can manage all dependencies and connect all parts of the solution.
If you want gui with c#, you'll have to install visual studio, there's a free community edition with all the features you'll need. Also it will make it so much easier for you. Use the right tool for the job.

**[EDIT]:**

There is a answer above which shows an example of how it is possible to achieve a workaround without using visual studio.

It is however important to know that I would do this only as a last resort as visual studio has tools to help with UI design that make it easier to build, test and run, and as of the time of edit (Feb 08, 2023), Visual Studio is still the only IDE which supports Hot Reload with all the most common UI frameworks include .NET Maui. Which by many is consider a must-have option for developing UI with C#.

**More on using vscode:**

Since the time of the original answer, the dotnet cli has significantly improved, has more templates and more options to build and run everything using the cli, which does make the gap between using Visual Studio and vscode smaller compared to 3 years ago.

Also a vscode extension named **.NET Meteor** was published not long ago, and quickly gaining popularity, it allows you to run and debug many different project types which were previously impossible with vscode, such as class libraries, WinUI, and even .NET Maui, and support using emulators. This extension further bridges the gap between vscode and Visual Studio. However as of right now it still doesn't have Hot Reload nor XAML Intellisense, which still means Visual Studio will be a better option with more features that massively increase productivity.

Comment: This is not an acceptable answer. The question asked here is : "How to create a GUI app in C# with Visual Studio Code?" and not "Can I create a GUI app in C# with Visual Studio Code?". Also maybe the author is on Linux and currently there are no Visual Studio release available on this system. And as shown in the upper response, this task is totally achievable in Visual Studio Code. It could have nice if you edited your answer when the other answer was published.

Comment: @theskyblockman I have now updated the answer, I hope you find this acceptable. I am sorry that I didn't edit it sooner, but I didn't get any update that another answer was posted so I simply didn't know or remember about this thread until I receive a notification of your comment. With that said, when you read answers on Stackoverflow it is important to note the date of the answer, and my answer was more than 2 years old, so take it with a grain of salt.

Comment: VSCode is NOT a "rich text editor". "rich text editor" is technically referring to RTF/markups formats. VSCode is a plain text editor.